# Drawing odd no. of rectangle for rows and columns

Tags: java, for-loop, logical-operators

I am trying to draw 5 (for example) rectangles on canvas, using `GC.drawRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height);`
After forth column rectangle should be drawn in next row as shown in the picture.[Picture, layout for the rectangles drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JczEU.png). I am not able to find some logic to draw rectangles as desired.
Here is what I was trying to do.

```
int col = (brushPanz-1) / 4;//gives column
int row = (brushPanz-1) % 4;//gives rows
for (int i = 0; i < brushPanz; i++) {
    GC.drawRectangle((i * 172 + 5), col * 78 + 5, 500 / ratio, 220 / ratio); 
}
```

Basically I want to use only one for loop to draw any number of rectangles. Someone, please help.

Comment: You don't describe how your result is failing but your row and column computations are reversed.  (Column should vary in 0..3 and row should grow from 0.)

Comment: In your comment, you have mixed cols and rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without trying to debug your position offsets versus your size, you need (a) to compute a new row/col for each rect, (b) to use those computed values to position your rect and (c) to correctly compute row vs. column.

```
for (int i = 0; i < brushPanz; i++) {
    int col = i % 4;//gives column
    int row = i / 4;//gives rows
    GC.drawRectangle((col * 172 + 5), row * 78 + 5, 500 / ratio, 220 / ratio);
}
```